# Problemas a la hora de compilar C++

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código sencillo solo para ilustrar el problema:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout << "Hola mundo!" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Como se darán cuenta es un simple "hola mundo", pero a la hora de compilar sale el siguiente error:

```
root@Ubuntu0:/home/lfgc# gcc -o example example.cpp 
/tmp/ccGcXhXQ.o: En la función `main':
example.cpp:(.text+0xe): referencia a `std::cout' sin definir
example.cpp:(.text+0x13): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' sin definir
example.cpp:(.text+0x1d): referencia a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' sin definir
example.cpp:(.text+0x28): referencia a `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' sin definir
/tmp/ccGcXhXQ.o: En la función `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
example.cpp:(.text+0x58): referencia a `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' sin definir
example.cpp:(.text+0x6d): referencia a `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anteriormente he podido compilar el programa desde un IDE, más específicamente CodeBlocks pero quiero solucionar ese problema respecto a la compilación por consola. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por lo que veo usas el comando gcc en cual es el compilador de c, pero iostrem es de c++.
Lo que puedes hacer es usar el comando g++ que es el compilador de c++.

```
ejemplo: g++ example.cpp -o example
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Fue eso, muchas gracias :)